# Carbon list of weeks in year

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I have function of return weeks in year:

```
function getWeek(){

    $today = \Carbon\Carbon::today();
    $date = $today->copy()->firstOfYear()->startOfDay();
    $eom = $today->copy()->endOfYear()->startOfDay();
  
    $dates = [];

    for($i = 1; $date->lte($eom); $i++){
        $startDate = $date->copy();
        while($date->dayOfWeek != \Carbon\Carbon::SUNDAY && $date->lte($eom)){
                $date->addDay(); 
            }
        
        $dates['w'.$i] = $startDate->format('d/m/Y') . ' - ' . $date->format('d/m/Y');
        $date->addDay();
    }
    
    return $dates;
}
```

And the function return 53 weeks in year 2022 but in 2022 is 52 weeks. This is a result of return `$dates`

[image]

How to change the function to return first position to return full dates of week (27/12/2021 - 02/01/2022) and the same at the last position in year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution always shows the complete weeks. Uses the ISO 8601 week number.
Only DateTime is required. The year was added for the key so that they are always unique.

```
$year = date_create('today')->format('Y');
//remove comment next line for test's
//$year = 2001;

$dtStart = date_create('2 jan '.$year)->modify('last Monday');
$dtEnd = date_create('last monday of Dec '.$year);

for($weeks = [];$dtStart <= $dtEnd;$dtStart->modify('+1 week')){
  $key = $dtStart->format('W-Y');
  $from = $dtStart->format('d/m/Y');
  $to = (clone $dtStart)->modify('+6 Days')->format('d/m/Y');
  $weeks[$key] = $from.' - '.$to;
}

var_export($weeks);
```

Since carbon is not required, you can also test it [here](https://3v4l.org/2vK30).

Comment: Thx @jsplit, this I need!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaken.

> w1->w53 = 52 weeks

Comment: The real problem I think is always returning the full dates of the weeks.